# Scan 2D ArrayList for unique elements in the first list

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

i've been stuck for hours now and can't find a solution.
I want to compare two ArrayLists where i want to put each unique element from one of the list into another arrayList.

For example, if my one arrayList contain {0,1,2,3} and i want to compare it to {{1},{2},{3}} i want to recieve {2} in my 'unqiue' arraylist
please help me

### AFTER EDIT

I will be more specific. ArrayList1={0,1,2,3,4} and ArrayList2={{0, 1} {0,1,2}} So what i want is to have the only unique from ArrayList1 in a single ArrayList. in this example i want ArrayList3= {3,4}

Comment: Sure you want to receive 2? wouldnt 0 be what you want? If you want to get 2 you also would get 1 and 3...?!

Comment: You could iterate through one list and see if the other list `contains(Object)` the element currently being iterated.

Comment: I'll edit my post again.

Answer (score 0):

You can use method [**boolean removeAll(Collection c)**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html#removeAll%28java.util.Collection%29) of `List`.

It will removes all the elements that are contained in the specified collection from this list. So after invoking this your list will contain unique elements.

Suppose you have `arrayList1` and `arrayList2` the you can compare them like this:

```
arrayList1.removeAll(arrayList2);
```

Now `arrayList1` contains only unique elements.

Answer (score 0):

If I am interpreting your question correctly, you want to form a new list of common elements in 2 lists? If so, iterate through one of the list and check to see if the second list `contains(Object)` that element, if so add it to the third list. I cannot provide a code sample at this very moment but when I get to a computer I will be glad to edit this (if necessary).

Edit:

The code would probably look something like this:

```
    private static <T> List<T> getUniqueList(final List<T> first, final List<T> second){
    final List<T> unique = new ArrayList<T>();
    for(final T element : first)
        if(second.contains(element))
            unique.add(element);
    return unique;
}
```

Or if you are using Java 8:

```
    private static <T> List<T> getUniqueList(final List<T> first, final List<T> second){
    final List<T> unique = new ArrayList<>();
    first.stream().filter(second::contains).forEach(unique::add);
    return unique;
}
```

Comment: yes, this is what i've been trying to do... I will be more specific. ArrayList1={0,1,2,3} and ArrayList2={{0, 1} {0,1,2}} So what i want is to have the only unique from ArrayList1 in a single ArrayList